# GetMyFeesEstimate API Amazon vba

Tags: excel, vba, amazon-web-services, api

I have a problem getting a reasonable answer from Amazon. The problem is only with `GetMyFeesEstimate`. The other stuff like `GetMyPriceForASIN` works. I'm trying to get a response with VBA/Excel.

Example Code from Amazon:

```
https://mws.amazonservices.de/Products/2011-10-01?
FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.MarketplaceId=A1PA6795UKMFR9
&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.IdType=ASIN
&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.IdValue=3828934897
&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.IsAmazonFulfilled=true
&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.Identifier=request1
&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.PriceToEstimateFees.ListingPrice.CurrencyCode=EUR
&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.PriceToEstimateFees.ListingPrice.Amount=30.00
&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.PriceToEstimateFees.Shipping.CurrencyCode=EUR
&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.PriceToEstimateFees.Shipping.Amount=3.99
&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.PriceToEstimateFees.Points.PointsNumber=0
&AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
&Action=GetMyFeesEstimate
&SellerId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
&SignatureVersion=2
&Timestamp=2018-01-07T10%3A26%3A27Z&Version=2011-10-01&Signature=bJJJorhyeKwejuddJs6Z%2BVYZZmKtm0CG2GAXTrShyZM%3D
```

If I try to use this signed request with my data I get the following mistake:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

Can someone help me with this?

[Here](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetMyPriceForASIN.html) is the Documentation from Amazon.

Comment: Where is the VBA code related to this?

Comment: Hey, that´s a very long vba code. is here any chance to upload a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown code on how you are signing the request.

Since you already have been succesful for one API, can you check if you that the decimal values you are using are exactly the same in signing string and POST request? 
Sometime excel stores values like 30.0 as 0.3E02 or something like that and this causes the signing string to be different from your post request.

I have used Amazon Scratchpad to create a POST and also to get a guidance on the signing string.
Please go to https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html
Once you enter the details on the left and click on submit, you can see the Request details and the signing string. If you create the request exactly as specified there and sign exactly as specified there, you shouldnt have a singing issue.

Here is the sample for your request:

POST /Products/2011-10-01?AWSAccessKeyId=

&Action=GetMyFeesEstimate

&SellerId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX

&SignatureVersion=2

&Timestamp=2018-06-12T04%3A19%3A55Z

&Version=2011-10-01

&Signature=vJLewLVH7FmUD8cpST8dD51GBUJkt6Aj9FADGLoCjNQ%3D

&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256

&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.MarketplaceId=A1PA6795UKMFR9

&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.IdType=ASIN

&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.IdValue=3828934897

&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.IsAmazonFulfilled=true

&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.Identifier=request1

&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.PriceToEstimateFees.ListingPrice.Amount=30.00

&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.PriceToEstimateFees.ListingPrice.CurrencyCode=EUR

&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.PriceToEstimateFees.Shipping.Amount=3.99

&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.PriceToEstimateFees.Shipping.CurrencyCode=EUR

&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.PriceToEstimateFees.Points.PointsNumber=0 HTTP/1.1

Host: mws.amazonservices.com

x-amazon-user-agent: AmazonJavascriptScratchpad/1.0 (Language=Javascript)

Content-Type: text/xml

Here is the string to sign. 
Note that you have to put CHR(10) for a new line. Do not put VBCRLF in the string.

POST
mws.amazonservices.com
/Products/2011-10-01
AWSAccessKeyId=&Action=GetMyFeesEstimate&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.IdType=ASIN&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.IdValue=3828934897&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.Identifier=request1&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.IsAmazonFulfilled=true&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.MarketplaceId=A1PA6795UKMFR9&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.PriceToEstimateFees.ListingPrice.Amount=30.00&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.PriceToEstimateFees.ListingPrice.CurrencyCode=EUR&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.PriceToEstimateFees.Points.PointsNumber=0&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.PriceToEstimateFees.Shipping.Amount=3.99&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.PriceToEstimateFees.Shipping.CurrencyCode=EUR&SellerId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2018-06-12T04%3A19%3A55Z&Version=2011-10-01